# select element unsing XPATH in Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, get, attributes

I would like to get the title of the following object:

```
<td class="Business">
  <img alt="Logo" title="Company Name" >
</td>
```

I tried:

```
title=driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//td[@class="Business"]').get_attribute("title")
```

but it doesnt seem to work. Can someone help plz?

Comment: Link to website would help

Comment: The `<td>` element itself does not have a title attribute.

Answer (score 0):

The `td` element doesn't have a `title` attribute; it's the `img` child element of the `td` which has the `title` attribute. So the XPath you want is:

```xpath
//td[@class='Business']/img
```